# How to know, which cell opened UiTableViewController?

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

I have two `UITableViewController`s: `SettingsViewController` and `DetailsViewController`. And I want one `Details` controller for different `Settings`, i.e. "Language", "Currency", "Visibility" etc.

So, I need to know in `DetailsViewController`, which cell from `SettingsViewController` opened it.

I'm not very good in Swift yet, so I build cells for `SettingsViewController` in Interface Builder and I have no `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method in its code. Do I need to implement this method? Or, maybe, I can get the particular cell by index (or by label name)? But for this I need to connect the whole `SettingsViewController` to `DetailsViewController`, and I don't know how to do it either.

In fact I need something like this in `DetailsViewController`:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    # if it was called by "Language" cell
        return 2
    # if it was called by "Currency" cell
        return 5
    # else
        return 7
}
```

Thanks for any help! If you need code of these controllers, I'll add it, but in fact there is nothing special in it, only standard methods with standard `return`s.

Comment: Get the cell which was selected in `prepareForSegue...` with `tableView.selectedRow`.

Comment: Thanks! I'll look at `prepareForSegue` method. If you can write the whole method in answer and add `tableView.selectedRow` to my code snippet from question, I'll happily accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to implement the `prepareForSegue:sender:` method as @dasdom said as below:

```
// SettingsViewController.swift
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "Storyboard Segue Identifier" {
        // then you get index with `indexPathForSelectedRow`
        if let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow() {
            let controller = segue.destinationViewController as DetailsViewController
            // configure the controller
            // controller.xxx = xxx
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use tableView's didSelectRowAtIndexPath and prepareForSegue:

```
let data = ["Language", "Currency", "Visibility"]
var dvcRowCount:Int?

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    switch indexPath.row {
    case 0: dvcRowCount = 2
    case 1: dvcRowCount = 3
    case 2: dvcRowCount = 4
    default: dvcRowCount = 1
    }
    performSegueWithIdentifier("showDetail", sender: self)
}
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    let dvc = segue.destinationViewController as DetailTableViewController
    dvc.rowCount = dvcRowCount
}
```

And in the detailTableViewController:

```
    var rowCount:Int?
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    //return 0 if the rowCount is not set
    return rowCount ?? 0
}
```

I uploaded the demo code at: https://github.com/vidaaudrey/SharingDetailTableView